# How to set a cool down for receiving packets of each client with c#?

Tags: c#

How can I set a cooldown for receiving a packet for each client with C#?

I have a program which connect to a game server as a player and receive packets from other players.

I want to set a cooldown for the packet from each player - something like if player1 sent an in-game message the next message won't take any effect unless the cool down of the first message finished.

My code which reads the packet:

```
public void ComingPacket(Packet current)
{
    if (current.Opcode == 0x2222)//Chat packet
    {
        string string1;
        string string2;
        switch (current.ReadUInt8())
        {
            case 2:
                string1= current.ReadAscii();//Player Name
                string2= current.ReadAscii();//Message
                if (string2 == "Hello")
                {
                    my code.........
                }
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Note: There are many players who send messages, not just 1.

Comment: Can you provide some code context? What do you mean? What have you tried?

Comment: @gunr2171 i have added the code which i want to set a cooldown for it. also i have looked around but no smth useful which can help me.

Comment: I don't think it's wise to slow down the actual rate of packet transfer. It would be better to limit the amount of user interactions.